# Struggling with proof using Induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction

We just learned induction, and I'm already stuck. I'll try my best to put my work into text.

1 − 2 + 2^2 − 2^3 + ... + (−1)^n(2^n) = (2^(n+1)(−1)^n + 1)/3

for all positive integers n.

Already have basis-step complete.

Inductive Step: Assume n=k, then...

1 − 2 + 2^2 − 2^3 + ... + (−1)^k(2^k) = (2^(k+1)(−1)^k + 1)/3

then k+1

1 − 2 + 2^2 − 2^3 + ... + (−1)^(k+1)(2^(k+1)) = (2^((k+1)+1)(−1)^(k+1) + 1)/3

---

(2^(k+1)(−1)^k + 1)/3 + (-1)^(k+1)2(k+1) = (2^(k+2)(−1)^(k+1) + 1)/3

(2^(k+1)(−1)^k + 1)/3 + ((-3)^(k+1)2(k+1))/3 = (2^(k+2)(−1)^(k+1) + 1)/3

This is where I start having trouble, re-arranging and dividing out things like 2^(k+1) or (-1)^(k+1) have led to nothing... I think.

---

I don't know if the work to the point is correct or not, but I've been mulling over this for quite a while now to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{1}(-1)^{k}(2^{k})=\frac{(−1)^{1}(2^{1+1})+1}{3}$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}(2^{k})=\frac{(−1)^{n}(2^{n+1})+1}{3}$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}(2^{k})=$

$\color\red{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}(2^{k})}+(-1)^{n+1}(2^{n+1})=$

$\color\red{\frac{(−1)^{n}(2^{n+1})+1}{3}}+(-1)^{n+1}(2^{n+1})=$

$\frac{(−1)^{n}(2^{n+1})+1}{3}+\frac{3(-1)^{n+1}(2^{n+1})}{3}=$

$\frac{(−1)^{n}(2^{n+1})+1+3(-1)^{n+1}(2^{n+1})}{3}=$

$\frac{(−1)^{n}(2^{n+1})+3(-1)^{n+1}(2^{n+1})+1}{3}=$

$\frac{(−1)^{n}(2^{n+1})(1+3(-1)^{1})+1}{3}=$

$\frac{(−1)^{n}(2^{n+1})(1-3)+1}{3}=$

$\frac{(−1)^{n}(2^{n+1})(-2)+1}{3}=$

$\frac{(−1)^{n}(2^{n+1})(-1)(2)+1}{3}=$

$\frac{(−1)^{n}(-1)(2^{n+1})(2)+1}{3}=$

$\frac{(−1)^{n+1}(2^{n+1+1})+1}{3}$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: Oh wow, I really had it. My ability to make it look like the RHS wasn't there though. Thanks for the full arithmetic!

Comment: @InductionNoob: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)